# How to get data from database using sequelize(nodejs) starting from row 10 to row 15

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to fetch data from database using sequelize starting from row 10 up to row 15 ordered by descending. Pls Help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, here it will skip the first 9 rows

```js
Project.findAll({ offset: 9, limit: 15 })
```